# "Sequence size" doesn't match row in Python?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

Essentially I am trying to calculate a value for a couple of fields after adding them. Below you can see how I am adding the fields and then an example on how my "for" statement is looping through the cursors to add values.

I keep getting an error: "TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row"

I'm not sure what to do about this. Is there a better method than to use the UpdateCursor updateRow statements?

```
fieldName = ["azVEqSet", "azVERis"]
try:
    arcpy.AddField_management(points, fieldName[0] ,"FLOAT")
    arcpy.AddField_management(points, fieldName[1] ,"FLOAT")
except:
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(points, [fieldName[0], fieldName[1]])
    arcpy.AddField_management(points, fieldName[0] ,"FLOAT")
    arcpy.AddField_management(points, fieldName[1] ,"FLOAT")

cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(points, ["azVEqSet", "azVERis", "POINT_X", "RASTERVALU", "POINT_Y"])
for row in cursor:
...
     numberInsert = ReturnedVariable
     row[0] = numberInsert
     cursor.updateRow([row])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
cursor.updateRow([row])
```

To:

```
cursor.updateRow(row)
```

**Explanation:**

- `row`, which you obtained from the [`arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000) is a [*sequence*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) (a [*tuple*](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), specifically) of a certain length expected by the `updateRow` method, and by wrapping `row` in brackets, you are creating a new sequence (a [*list*](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), specifically) of length 1, which is not the length expected.